# Issue while Importing JSON in Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to Import JSON File in one of my .ts file.However,when I do a require.I am getting a runtime Error.

```
public serverConfiguration = require('./serverConfiguration.json');
```

This is the way I have added my JSON file in .ts.

On running the Webpage, I am getting below error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/config/serverConfiguration.json.js
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/config/serverConfiguration.json.js
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
Error loading http://localhost:3000/config/serverConfiguration.json.js as "./serverConfiguration.json" from http://localhost:3000/config/config.js
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
Error loading http://localhost:3000/config/serverConfiguration.json.js as "./serverConfiguration.json" from http://localhost:3000/config/config.js
```

I have made an entry in my System.config.js , but still no Luck.

```
  packages: {
    serverConfiguration:{
        defaultExtension : 'json'
    },
```

I have tried importing the JSON File also,but i presume,the same cannot be done for a JSON File.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ James Donnelly....Can you provide the Link for the similar Question.I tried but didn't found anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you export the json:

```
var json = [{}]
exports.json = json;
```

Now your require will work as :

```
var json = require('./serverConfiguration'); //<---change the extension to js
```

Comment: @Jai....Should I make changes and add above piece of code in my .ts where in I want to import json or in some other file?